# NetStream.Buffer.flush prevents form seeking

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, rtmpd

I have a flash player that I use for streaming prerecorded flv sounds. I have forward and backward buttons which seek forward/backward into the sound while playing.

The problem I get is that when I use shorter sound like 30 seconds, when 10 seconds near the end I get this message from the player **"NetStream.Buffer.flush"** which in turns does this **"Data has finished streaming, and the remaining buffer is emptied"**, so I cannot seek near end of the file.

How can I fix this?

I already put **inBufferSeek** to true and set **bufferTime** to 5.

Is this problem with Flash/As3 or it is something with the server? (I use crtmp opensource server)

Comment: Do you have keyframes near the end of the flv?

Comment: I dont think so. I dont do anything with keyframes. And also dont know how to check if they are added somehow.

Comment: That may be something you'll want to check on with the person creating the flvs. You can only seek to a location in the flv with a keyframe. Occasionally to save space, people will remove keyframes.

Comment: OK. I got the metadata of the file and I get lots of undefines except these duration: 33.719
audiodatarate: 125
filesize: 1489341
audiocodecid : 3

Comment: keyframes part is undefined in metadata of the flv.

Comment: You're not going to get keyframes in the metadata. Pretty much the only thing you can do besides realizing that you can't seek to a certain area is ask the content creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with presence/absence of key frames. It is purely flash-side. Seeking should work just fine. Here is a demonstration [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LYTNy7xR]

Comment: Yes but I don't use video, only audio. Is it maybe the flv file I am using is corrupted or somehow broken? I encode audio using speex and pcm in flv file. Helper tool ffmpeg.